# when open xml file with notepad it works fine

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I am generating an xml file using C# code. 
Client uploads this xml on a url to validate its data but it fails to validate. Then client opened this downloaded xml file with notepad and saves this file (not save as) without making any changes then try again to validate against the url, it works fine. I am not able to understand the root cause of this issue. I have also tried some different ways to download the xml file but all fails.

Comment: Can you post your code ? , how you create those files ?

Answer (score 1):

**Cause**

Then it must be something related to encoding.

**Try this**

Check the encoding in the files you saved using *save* and using *save as*. Use the encoding same as in the file you saved using *save as*.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I resolved the issue. To resolve the issue,  write a line (Empty) and save the file. It is the process that we followed manually to work with file. We create the file but system does not considered as that a saved file. Some web sites required the file properly saved in the system that is the reason I followed this approach.   This is the sample code that you can user after creating the file at last. StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(xmlPath, true);
                        sw.WriteLine();
                        sw.Close();

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. To resolve the issue, we wrote a line (Empty) and saved the file. It was the process that we followed manually to work with the file. We created the file but system did not consider it as a saved file. Some websites required the file to be saved properly in the system which is why I followed this approach. This is the sample code that can be used after creating the file.

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(xmlPath, true);
sw.WriteLine();
sw.Close();
```